# how to add remainders in iOS with start date and end date by weekly/Monthly/every X days?

Tags: objective-c, uilocalnotification

How to add Pill remainders in iOS  with start date and end date by twice in week/weekly/Monthly/ every x days/ daily/

Answer (score 0):

Using  `UILocalNotification`

its provide the fire data also u can manage the time like below

```
localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
```